Analogy between Jones waveplates calculus and Qiskit unitary gates calculus
I am trying to understand a relation between Jones calculus, where we work with polarization, and the same implementation in Qiskit quantum schemes.
Let me explain what I mean with examples. After that, I will ask my questions.
Suppose we have a horizontally polarized photon in state $|H\rangle$ which in qubit representation is $|0\rangle$ (and in the future, I will write $|0\rangle$ when I mean horizontally polarized photon).
Now, this photon is going through a half-wave plate (HWP), which represents next (without global phase considering):
$H = \begin{bmatrix}
    cos^2(\alpha)- sin^2(\alpha) & 2cos(\alpha) sin(\alpha) \\
    2cos(\alpha) sin(\alpha) & sin^2(\alpha) - cos^2(\alpha) \\
\end{bmatrix}$
Where $\alpha$ is an angle HWP is rotated. It is known that angle of polarization of photon (we will call it angle $\beta$) after HWP will be twice larger of angle $\alpha$. For example, if angle of HWP $\alpha=\pi/6$, than, after HWP, angle polarization of photon will be $\beta=\pi/3$.
In this case, HWP matrix will be the next:
$H(\pi/6) = \begin{bmatrix}
    cos^2(\pi/6)- sin^2(\pi/6) & 2cos(\pi/6) sin(\pi/6) \\
    2cos(\pi/6) sin(\pi/6) & sin^2(\pi/6) - cos^2(\pi/6) \\
\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac 1 2 & \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 \\
    \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 & - \frac 1 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
If our input statevector of photon is:
$|0\rangle = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$
Statevector after HWP with $\alpha=\pi/6$ will be:
$\begin{bmatrix} \frac 1 2 \\ \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac 1 2 & \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 \\
    \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 & - \frac 1 2 \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$
Now, let us consider the same example, but through Qiskit implementation.
We know that any quantum state can be represented the next:
$|\psi \rangle = cos(\frac \theta 2)| 0 \rangle + e^{i \phi} sin(\frac \theta 2)| 1 \rangle$
Where $\theta$ is colatitude in the Bloch sphere.
Technically, RY gate in Qiskit does the same as HWP with light polarization. And relation between $\beta$ and $\theta$ is $\theta = 2\beta$. Then, relation between angle of HWP $\alpha$ and $\theta$ is $\theta = 4\alpha$.
If we have initial $|0 \rangle$ state, we can implement Qiskit RY gate:
$RY(\theta)=\begin{bmatrix}
    cos(\frac \theta 2) & -sin(\frac \theta 2) \\
    sin(\frac \theta 2) & cos(\frac \theta 2) \\
\end{bmatrix}$
with $\alpha = \pi / 6 \rightarrow \theta=4\pi/6 \rightarrow \frac \theta 2 =\frac \pi3 $:
$RY(\pi / 6)=\begin{bmatrix}
    cos(\frac \pi3) & -sin(\frac \pi3) \\
    sin(\frac \pi3) & cos(\frac \pi3) \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac 1 2 & - \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 \\
    \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 & \frac 1 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
And result vector remains the same:
$\begin{bmatrix} \frac 1 2 \\ \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac 1 2 & - \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 \\
    \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 & \frac 1 2 \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$
Regardless that HWP and RY matrices are different, results are the same. I tried different angles $\alpha$, starting from $| 0 \rangle$ states - result statevectors are the same.
Now, I want to show a similar situation, but with quarter-wave plates (QWP).
QWP in Jones calculus with arbitrary angle $\alpha$ (without global phase considering) is the next:
$Q = \begin{bmatrix}
    cos^2(\alpha) + i sin^2(\alpha) & (1-i)sin(\alpha) cos(\alpha) \\
    (1-i)sin(\alpha) cos(\alpha) & sin^2(\alpha) + i cos^2(\alpha) \\
\end{bmatrix}$
According to main purpose of QWP, it makes a phase shifting between horizontal and vertical parts of photon polarization by $\pi /2$.
Then, if we want to implement it in Qiskit, firstly we need to rotate our state around Y axis by RY gate with angle $\theta$, after it rotate around Z axis by RZ gate with every time fixed angle $\pi /2$
Let's see one more example but this time with QWP.
Again we start with state $| 0 \rangle$ and send it through QWP with angle $\alpha = \pi/6$.
This QWP will have the next representation:
$Q(\pi/6) = \begin{bmatrix}
    cos^2(\pi/6) + i sin^2(\pi/6) & (1-i)sin(\pi/6) cos(\pi/6) \\
    (1-i)sin(\pi/6) cos(\pi/6) & sin^2(\pi/6) + i cos^2(\pi/6) \\
\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}
    0.75 + 0.25i & \frac {\sqrt 3} 4 - i \frac {\sqrt 3} 4 \\
    \frac {\sqrt 3} 4 - i \frac {\sqrt 3} 4 & 0.25 + 0.75i \\
\end{bmatrix}$
Then, statevector after QWP will be:
$\begin{bmatrix} \frac 3 4 + \frac i 4 \\  \frac {\sqrt 3} 4 - i \frac {\sqrt 3} 4 \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    0.75 + 0.25i & \frac {\sqrt 3} 4 - i \frac {\sqrt 3} 4 \\
    \frac {\sqrt 3} 4 - i \frac {\sqrt 3} 4 & 0.25 + 0.75i \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$
or, after removing the global phase, it will be
$\approx$ \begin{bmatrix} \frac {\sqrt 10} 4 \\ 0.2739 - 0.5477i \\ \end{bmatrix}
Now,we will do the same, but in qiskit. For QWP case I noticed, that relation between $\theta$ and $\alpha$ is $\theta = 2 \alpha$, because with angle $\alpha=\pi / 4$ horizontal state is fully transfers to the circular polarization state.
We start from $| 0 \rangle$ state and first change its colatitude:
$\begin{bmatrix} \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 \\  \frac 1  2 \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 & - \frac 1 2 \\
    \frac 1 2 & \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$
And after implementation of RZ with the fixed angle $\frac {\pi} 2$ we will have the final vector $\begin{bmatrix} \frac {\sqrt 6} 4 - \frac {\sqrt 6i} 4 \\ \frac {\sqrt 2} 4 + \frac {\sqrt 2i} 4 \\ \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 \\ \frac i 2 \\ \end{bmatrix}$
We can see, that final statevectors from Jones calculus and Qiskit implementation are different:
$\begin{bmatrix} \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 \\ \frac i 2 \\ \end{bmatrix} \neq \begin{bmatrix} \frac {\sqrt 10} 4 \\ 0.2739 - 0.5477i \\ \end{bmatrix}$
Could you, please, explain what is wrong? Or, could you explain, please, how should I correctly map Jones calculus using HWP, QWP matrices with Qiskit calculation, using RX, RY, RZ or universal U rotation matrices in Bloch sphere.
Thank you!

A HWP introduces a phase shift of $\pi$ between the fast and slow axis. Assuming the fast axis is along the direction of the horizontal polarization, you can express this with a $Z$ gate (up to a global phase):
$$J_H = \begin{bmatrix}e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\frac{-\pi}{2}} \end{bmatrix} = e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} = e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}} Z$$
A QWP introduces a phase shift of $\pi/2$ between the fast and slow axis. You can express this with a $S$ gate (up to a global phase):
$$J_Q = \begin{bmatrix}e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\frac{-\pi}{4}} \end{bmatrix} = e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & i \end{bmatrix} = e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}} S$$
Rotating the plates by an angle $\alpha$ is mathematically equivalent to rotating the photon polarization in the opposite direction, then apply $J_H$ (or $J_Q$), and finally rotate the polarization back. This is equivalent to applying an $RY$ gate of twice the physical angle before and after the phase-shift.
So fo the half-wave plate you have:
$$ J_H(\alpha) = RY(2\alpha) \, Z \,RY(-2\alpha) .$$
Similarly, for the quarter-wave plate:
$$ J_Q(\alpha) = RY(2\alpha) \, S \,RY(-2\alpha).$$
These two expressions will give you matrices that are identical to the ones you defined above as $H$ and $Q$, respectively.

Thank you very much for the explanation! I totally forgot to think, that both HWP and QWP have phase shifting. I have checked the code and it works!
